# Laravel. Свойство fillable и сценарии

Tags: laravel, framework, php

Есть свойство `fillable`, которое представляет из себя массив, который позволяет заполнить указанные поля при массовом присвоении. 
Если, например, у меня есть поля которые должны заполниться при одном сценарии, и не должны заполняться при другом?
С валидацией здесь понятно - указываем `rules` для каждого отдельно, но как быть с `fillable`? Ведь, если форма отправится с полем, которое мне не нужно при определенном сценарии и его не будет в `rules`, но будет в `fillable`, то это поле присвоится и соответственно сохранится? В `Yii` это можно сделать указанием атрибута `safe` в `rules` и указанием сценария (`on => 'scenario'`). Как это можно сделать в *Laravel*?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

`$fillable` - это для безопасности. Если поле не нужно передавать в форму, достаточно его удалить из массива значений формы перед отправкой в модель.